# Image Resize/Crop Class

Tags: php, optimization, object-oriented

I've combined some of my own functions with a function I found and I'm curious to know what others think of it. It will be used to upload and resize/crop images that are jpeg, jpg, png.

```
<?php
class ImageUploader {
    var $multiple_file_upload = true;
    var $max_size = 1024;
    var $mime_types = array('bmp' => 'image/bmp', 'gif' => 'image/gif', 'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg', 'jpg' => 'image/jpeg', 'png' => 'image/png');
    var $allowed_extensions;
    function __construct() {

    }

    function get_image_information($file) {
        return getimagesize($file);
    }

    function get_image_extension($file) {
        return pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    }

    function resize_image($source_image, $destination_filename, $width = 100, $height = 100, $quality = 70, $crop = false) {

        $image_data = $this -> get_image_information($source_image);

        switch( $image_data['mime'] ) {
            case 'image/gif' :
                $get_func = 'imagecreatefromgif';
                $suffix = ".gif";
                break;
            case 'image/jpeg' :
                $get_func = 'imagecreatefromjpeg';
                $suffix = ".jpg";
                break;
            case 'image/png' :
                $get_func = 'imagecreatefrompng';
                $suffix = ".png";
                break;
        }

        $img_original = call_user_func($get_func, $source_image);
        $old_width = $image_data[0];
        $old_height = $image_data[1];
        $new_width = $width;
        $new_height = $height;
        $src_x = 0;
        $src_y = 0;
        $current_ratio = round($old_width / $old_height, 2);
        $desired_ratio_after = round($width / $height, 2);
        $desired_ratio_before = round($height / $width, 2);

        if ($old_width < $width || $old_height < $height) {
            /**
             * The desired image size is bigger than the original image.
             * Best not to do anything at all really.
             */
            return false;
        }

        /**
         * If the crop option is left on, it will take an image and best fit it
         * so it will always come out the exact specified size.
         */
        if ($crop) {
            /**
             * create empty image of the specified size
             */
            $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

            /**
             * Landscape Image
             */
            if ($current_ratio > $desired_ratio_after) {
                $new_width = $old_width * $height / $old_height;
            }

            /**
             * Nearly square ratio image.
             */
            if ($current_ratio > $desired_ratio_before && $current_ratio < $desired_ratio_after) {
                if ($old_width > $old_height) {
                    $new_height = max($width, $height);
                    $new_width = $old_width * $new_height / $old_height;
                } else {
                    $new_height = $old_height * $width / $old_width;
                }
            }

            /**
             * Portrait sized image
             */
            if ($current_ratio < $desired_ratio_before) {
                $new_height = $old_height * $width / $old_width;
            }

            /**
             * Find out the ratio of the original photo to it's new, thumbnail-based size
             * for both the width and the height. It's used to find out where to crop.
             */
            $width_ratio = $old_width / $new_width;
            $height_ratio = $old_height / $new_height;

            /**
             * Calculate where to crop based on the center of the image
             */
            $src_x = floor((($new_width - $width) / 2) * $width_ratio);
            $src_y = round((($new_height - $height) / 2) * $height_ratio);
        }
        /**
         * Don't crop the image, just resize it proportionally
         */
        else {
            if ($old_width > $old_height) {
                $ratio = max($old_width, $old_height) / max($width, $height);
            } else {
                $ratio = max($old_width, $old_height) / min($width, $height);
            }

            $new_width = $old_width / $ratio;
            $new_height = $old_height / $ratio;

            $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
        }

        /**
         * Where all the real magic happens
         */
        imagecopyresampled($new_image, $img_original, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $new_width, $new_height, $old_width, $old_height);

        /**
         * Save it as a JPG File with our $destination_filename param.
         */
        imagejpeg($new_image, $destination_filename, $quality);

        /**
         * Destroy the evidence!
         */
        imagedestroy($new_image);
        imagedestroy($img_original);

        /**
         * Return true because it worked and we're happy. Let the dancing commence!
         */
        return true;
    }

}
?>
```

It works fine but any improvements or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: var is depricated use protected,public or private.

Comment: You shouldn't have member variables when you don't use them in functions. And your functions should also have protected,public or private.

Comment: Skip all useless comments. Just comment the intention and not the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints for (not) commenting your code.

Change:

```
/**
 * Landscape Image
 */
if ($current_ratio > $desired_ratio_after) {
```

To:

```
$isLandscape=$current_ratio > $desired_ratio_after;
if ($isLandscape) {
```

Or:

```
if ($old_width < $width || $old_height < $height) {
        /**
         * The desired image size is bigger than the original image.
         * Best not to do anything at all really.
         */
        return false;
}
```

To:

```
$toSmallToResize = $old_width < $width || $old_height < $height
if ($toSmallToResize) return false;
```

(Maybe the `||` should be a `&&` ?)

As I said in the comments, get rid of all comments without new informations for the reader.

You could also move your switch into a separate method with a nice name to reduce the length of your main method. And the crop and resize_only part are also suitable for a private method. (This methods would also be very easily to test in PHPUnit; just a bunch of numbers and no real images required.)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ideas mixed together that complicate the code:

- Manipulating an image.
- Uploading an image.

Separate the concerns into two different classes (e.g., `SimpleImage` and `SecureImageUpload`).

See the [SimpleImage class](http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-image-resizing.php) for a reasonably designed class that handles image manipulation. It has methods to resize, scale, load, and save image files of [various formats](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/2743.html). I'd recommend that you extend the `SimpleImage` class to include methods that expose the extra functionality you desire.

Encapsulation means that object data is manipulated by exposing methods to other objects. For example:

```
$image->load( "filename.jpg" );
$image->scale( 100 );
$image->save( "thumbnails/filename.jpg" );
```

Securely handling image file uploads in PHP is a daunting task to do correctly. See:

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32852/risks-of-a-php-image-upload-form
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166762/php-image-upload-security-check-list
- http://nullcandy.com/php-image-upload-security-how-not-to-do-it/
- http://www.net-security.org/dl/articles/php-file-upload.pdf
- http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2009/12/28/8-basic-rules-to-implement-secure-file-uploads/